# What is the recommended hotfixing flow with Git?

Tags: git

I am looking for the cleanest way to merge a hotfix back into my `develop` branch in the following scenario:

```
*   81bbef3 (HEAD -> main) Merge pull request #2 from hotfix/1
|\  
| * 41b9e72 (hotfix/1) Hotfix to main
|/  
*   33af83a Merge pull request #1 from develop
|\  
| * acfa468 (develop) Make change in develop
|/  
* 3caead4 Create README.md
```

Obviously, I can do `$ git merge --no-ff hotfix/1`, but that leaves me with:

```
*   d6b0e10 (HEAD -> develop) Merge branch 'hotfix/1' into develop
|\  
| | *   81bbef3 (main) Merge pull request #2 from hotfix/1
| | |\  
| | |/  
| |/|   
| * | 41b9e72 (hotfix/1) Hotfix to main
| |/  
| *   33af83a Merge pull request #1 from develop
| |\  
| |/  
|/|   
* | acfa468 Make change in develop
|/  
* 3caead4 Create README.md
```

Which means merge commits from `main` are now also on `develop`.

Is there a way to only merge `41b9e72` into `develop`, and avoid conflicts at the same time?

Comment: You could use [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)

Comment: In which case I will end up with a duplicate of `41b9e72` on branch `main` next time I merge `develop` into it?

Comment: Yes............